# Why are two of my modals working but any new ones wo

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have been trying to implement modals into my single-page site. the first two worked but the new ones won't and I can not figure out why.

The userModal and contactModal work perfectly but the new GrubIIModal does not and I have triple-checked my code. I am losing my mind over this.

Here is my current code (I have removed most links from the code because stack overflow kept telling me my question was spam)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pixelwolf.net</title>
  <style>
    /* Reset default margin and padding for the body and HTML elements */
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Hide scrollbars */
      background-color: #008080;
      /* Blue-green background color */
    }

    body {
      background-size: cover;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      /* You can choose a more suitable font */
    }

    #taskbar {
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      /* Light grey taskbar */
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 4px 0;
      /* Reduced padding */
      text-align: center;
      /* Hard, sharp bevel effect */
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }

    .start-button-container {
      width: 90px;
      /* Reduce start button width to 90px */
      float: left;
      /* Align to the left within the taskbar */
    }

    #start-button {
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      /* Grey start button */
      color: #000;
      /* Text color */
      width: 100%;
      /* Button takes full width of the container */
      height: 25px;
      /* Adjusted height */
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      /* Center the button text horizontally */
      line-height: 25px;
      /* Center the button text vertically */
      position: relative;
      /* Hard, sharp bevel effect for the button */
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-left: 2px solid #fff;
      border-right: 2px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
      z-index: 1;
      /* Ensure the button is above the menu */
    }

    .popup-container {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      /* Align 20px above the bottom */
      left: 0;
      width: 150px;
      /* Fixed width for alignment */
      display: none;
      z-index: 2;
      /* Ensure the menu is above the button */
    }

    .popup {
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      /* Grey menu background */
      background-image: url('https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/PopupImage.png');
      /* Specify the image URL */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /* Prevent image repetition */
      background-position: left bottom;
      /* Align the image to the bottom left */
      background-size: 30px auto;
      /* Set the width to 35 pixels and maintain the aspect ratio */
      border: 2px solid #000;
      /* Border for the menu */
      width: 250px;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      /* Hard, sharp bevel effect for the popup */
      padding-left: 35px;
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-left: 2px solid #fff;
      border-right: 2px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
      min-height: 200px;
    }

    .start-button-container:hover .popup-container {
      /* Show the menu on hover */
      display: block;
    }

    .popup ul {
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      /* Add a 10px bar on the left side */
      list-style-type: none;
      /* Hide bullet points */
    }

    .menu-item {
      padding: 5px 0;
      text-align: left;
      /* Align menu items to the left */
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      /* Remove border between menu items */
      /* Add hover effect */
      transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      /* Center items vertically */
      height: 10px;
    }

    .menu-item:hover {
      background-color: #000080;
      /* Blue background on hover */
      color: #fff;
      /* White text on hover */
    }

    .menu-item:last-child {
      border: none;
    }

    .sub-menu {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
      display: none;
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      /* Grey submenu background */
      /* Hard bevel border for the submenu */
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-left: 2px solid #fff;
      border-right: 2px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
      width: 250px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* Include padding in width calculation */
    }

    .sub-menu:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 50px;
      /* Adjust the width as needed */
      height: 100%;
    }

    .sub-menu img {
      max-width: 15px;
      /* Adjust the image size as needed */
      height: auto;
    }

    .sub-menu-text {
      position: relative;
      left: 5px;
      /* Adjust the positioning as needed */
      height: 12px;
    }

    .menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
      display: block;
    }

    .desktop-icon-container {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 65px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .desktop-icon img {
      max-width: 60px;
      height: auto;
    }

    .desktop-icon-text {
      color: white;
      /* White placeholder text color */
      align-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-top: -2px;
    }

    .clock-container {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      bottom: 50%;
      /* Vertically align to the center */
      transform: translate(0, 50%);
      /* Vertically center using transform */
      font-size: 14px;
      color: black;
      /* Set the font color to black */
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      /* Grey background */
      /* Inverted bevel border with dark edge on left and top */
      border-top: 2px solid #000;
      border-left: 2px solid #000;
      border-right: 2px solid #fff;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
      padding: 4px;
      /* Padding inside the container */
    }

    .copywriter-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
      font-size: 14px;
      color: black;
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      border: none;
      /* Removed the bevel */
      padding: 4px;
    }

    /* Modal CSS */
    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 985px;
      height: 688px;
      background-image: url('https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/ExplorerWindow.png');
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      padding: 20px;
      /* Add padding to the modal content */
      padding-top: 60px;
      /* Add extra padding to the top of the modal */
    }

    .modal-button {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
      background-color: transparent;
      /* Button background color */
      color: #fff;
      /* Button text color */
      border: 0px solid #007bff;
      /* Button border */
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      /* Button border radius */
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      /* Remove underline from anchor */
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Style for the container div */
    .about-container {
      width: 900px;
      height: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      /* Center the container horizontally */
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      /* White background color */
      padding: 20px;
      /* Add some padding to the container */
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* Include padding in width and height */
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      /* Choose your desired font */
      border: 0px solid #fff;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    /* Style for the square image */
    .profile-image {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      float: left;
      /* Float the image to the left */
      margin-right: 20px;
      /* Add some space to the right of the image */
      background-image: url('https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Evan256Pixeled.png');
      background-size: cover;
      /* Cover the entire square with the image */
    }

    /* Style for the about content */
    .about-content {
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Clear the float and prevent content from wrapping around the image */
      border-left: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
      padding-left: 18px;
    }

    /* Style for the text in the about content */
    .about-text {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      text-align: justify;
      /* Justify the text for a clean look */
    }

    /* Style for the LinkedIn link */
    .linkedin-link {
      display: block;
      /* Make the link a block-level element */
      margin-top: 10px;
      /* Add some space above the link */
    }

    /* Style the form container */
    .contact-form {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    /* Style form labels and inputs */
    .contact-form label {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .contact-form input[type="text"],
    .contact-form input[type="email"],
    .contact-form textarea {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the reCAPTCHA container */
    .g-recaptcha {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .contact-form input[type="submit"] {
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      color: white;
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-left: 2px solid #fff;
      border-right: 2px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .contact-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      border-top: 2px solid #fff;
      border-left: 2px solid #fff;
      border-right: 2px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="taskbar">
    <div class="start-button-container">
      <div id="start-button"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/WindowWolf32.png" style="width:20px; margin-right:3px;vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom:4px;"> Start</div>
      <div class="popup-container">
        <ul class="popup">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Joy.png" style="margin-right:4px; width:18px;">
            <span class="menu-item-text">Games</span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item">
                <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Joy.png" style="width:12px;">
                <a href="#GrubIIModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="modal-button">
                  <span class="sub-menu-text">Grub II</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item">
                <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Computer.png" style="width:12px;">
                <span class="sub-menu-text">Submenu 2</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Computer.png" style="margin-right:4px; width:18px;">
            <span class="menu-item-text">Program 2
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Computer.png" style="width:12px;">
                  <span class="sub-menu-text">Submenu 1</span>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                  <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Computer.png" style="width:12px;">
                  <span class="sub-menu-text">Submenu 2</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clock-container" id="clock"></div>
    <div class="copywriter-container">Copyright Evan Sorrell (pixelwolf) <script>
        document.write(/\d{4}/.exec(Date())[0])
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Desktop Icons -->
  <div id="desktop">
    <div class="desktop-icon-container">
      <div class="desktop-icon">
        <a href="#userModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="modal-button">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/User.png" alt="User">
        </a>
        <div class="desktop-icon-text">User</div>
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-icon" id="icon2">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAVDmpH88mNlBgBQxAhuHHQ" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Movie.png" alt="Icon 2">
        </a>
        <div class="desktop-icon-text">YouTube</div>
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-icon" id="icon3">
        <a href="#ContactModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="modal-button">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Mail.png" alt="Icon 2">
        </a>
        <div class="desktop-icon-text">Contact</div>
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-icon" id="icon4">
        <a href="https://news.pixelwolf.net" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Newspaper.png" target="_blank" alt="Icon 2">
        </a>
        <div class="desktop-icon-text">Blog</div>
      </div>
      <!-- test Modal -->
      <div class="desktop-icon" id="icon5">
        <a href="#GrubIIModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="modal-button">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Mail.png" alt="Icon 2">
        </a>
        <div class="desktop-icon-text">Test</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Desktop Icons -->
  <div class="overlay-window" id="window1">
  </div>

  <div class="overlay-window" id="window2">
  </div>

  <!-- User Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="userModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="userModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="about-container">
            <div class="profile-image"></div>
            <div class="about-content">
              <div class="about-text">
                <p>For years I tried my hand at many things, in the early years I started with a keen interest in web development after my father gave me a beginner's HTML book. At that time Geo Cities was the go-to free hosting platform, and I filled pages upon pages with useless gifs and "cool pictures" with god-awful contrasting colors.</p>
                <p>As I became more confident and tech-savvy, I continued to develop other interests from photography and video production, but no one thing truly filled that creative need.</p>
                <p>In late 2020, I decided to dive head-first into game development and years later here I am. Combining all of the skills that I have learned over the years into this amazing hobby.</p>
                <p>So that is it, that is my journey until now! Join me as I continue to develop these skills, improve my 3D modeling and texturing, build funky websites, and just generally have fun!</p>
              </div>

              <table style="width: 60%;">
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/evansorrell/" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/LinkedIn.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">LinkedIn</a></td>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://www.cgtrader.com/42pixels" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/CGTrader.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">CG Trader</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://sketchfab.com/ThePixelWolf" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Sketchfab.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">Sketchfab</a></td>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://ko-fi.com/thepixelwolf" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Ko-Fi.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">Ko-Fi</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://twitter.com/ThePixelWolf" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/x.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">X</a></td>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAVDmpH88mNlBgBQxAhuHHQ" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/YT.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">YouTube</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://pixelwolfnet.itch.io/" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/itch.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">Itch.io</a></td>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://gamejolt.com/@ThePixelwolf" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/GameJolt.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">GamJolt</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="linkedin-link" href="https://pixelwolf.substack.com/?utm_source=substack&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=substack_profile" target="_blank"><img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/SubStack.png" style="width:16px;margin-right: 5px;">SubStack</a></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- User Contact -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ContactModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="userModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p style="width:300px; font-weight:200; margin-top: 80px; margin-left:290px;"> Welcome to the exciting world of Pixelwolf where old school vibes meet new technologies. You know the drill, Drop me a line, and lets start a dialogue.</p>

          <div class="contact-form">
            <form action="process_form.php" method="post">
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>

              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

              <label for="message">Message:</label>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" required></textarea>

              <label for="math_captcha">Math CAPTCHA: What is 2 + 2?</label>
              <input type="number" id="math_captcha" name="math_captcha" required>

              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <script>
              // Generate a random math CAPTCHA question
              const generateMathCaptcha = () => {
                const num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                const num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                const sum = num1 + num2;
                const captchaQuestion = `What is ${num1} + ${num2}?`;
                document.querySelector("#math_captcha").setAttribute("data-answer", sum);
                document.querySelector("label[for='math_captcha']").textContent = captchaQuestion;
              };
              // Initialize math CAPTCHA
              generateMathCaptcha();
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Grub II Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="GrubIIModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="GrubIIModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://pixelwolf.net/images/icons/Grub2.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function updateClock() {
      const now = new Date();
      const hours = (now.getHours() % 12 || 12).toString();
      const minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const period = now.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      const clockElement = document.getElementById('clock');
      clockElement.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes} ${period}`;
    }
    setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    updateClock(); // Initial update
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `#GrubIIModal` modal is located inside another modal. Move it out from the `#ContactModal` element and it should work.

Comment: I did a have a look and found to rogue closing </div> however I have fixed that an the modal still will not show

Comment: I removed the  aria-hidden="true" tag from the modal container and now it all of a sudden works